# Which dotfile manager should I use for advanced dotfile management?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to get rid of my custom shell scripts for managing dotfiles (`~/.*` files and `~/.*/` directories in the HOME directory). In addition the tool needs to be capable of managing IDE specific files as well (see requirements below). The "bare repository and alias method" could potentially be an option. According to [it's usage explanation](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11070797) it seems easy and w.o. limitations. However probably it has limitations. Configuration management tools like Ansible seem too heavyweight for me.

Use case/requirements:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Mate
- as little dependencies of the tool to setup as possible (ideally shell script based)
- easy to use command line interface
- must support easy configuration of private and working setup (most configuration is the same like Spacemacs config, little configuration is different like e.g. git config)
- IDE: Spacemacs (`~/.spacemacs`, but all the stuff in `~/.emacs.d/private/`)
- shell: zshell (`.zshrc` + oh-my-zsh)
- terminal multiplexer: terminator (`.config/terminator/config`)
- support git based version control
- may not require manual copying and/or symlinking file
- free and open source

Possible choices:

- ["bare repository and alias method"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles#Tracking_dotfiles_directly_with_Git)
- [rcm](https://github.com/thoughtbot/rcm)
- [YADM](https://github.com/TheLocehiliosan/yadm)

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen to your home files? Save a copy, and if you edit a file then save that as a new version?

Comment: Yes, I want to version control the files in a git repository. It's essentially I want to manage the config like provided via "bare repository and alias method". I'm just not sure if this approach suffers from some limitations. It would be better to try rcm or yadm then...